# Where is my privileges list?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page

The design of my profile page changed today. Now I can't see the link to my privileges. Where is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's back where it always was. That change [was not supposed to go live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271936/profile-picture-displays-improperly-on-new-dashboard) - sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I cannot accept this as an answer. Shows an Error ... :-)

Comment: Slow down, you move too fast... You gotta make the morning last...